# android + gradle: multi-project w/ library projects

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We have a multi-project setup consisting of both app and library projects. something like this,

```
top -
  |- android-build (build tools here)
  |- android-help
     |- helper (app module)
  |- android-setup
     |- setup (app module)
  |- android-common
     |- common (library module)
     |- common-style (library module)
```

each of the projects under `top` are independent. the app folders reference the libraries via a maven dependency (so the libs needs to be built first obviously).

I'd like to define a build script, in the `android-build` folder, that can build all of the apps and libraries, and as a bonus, be loaded into android studio to have all the projects accessible together.

I've done this in the `android-build/settings/gradle`,

```
def rootDir = new File( androidBuild + "/.." ) // androidBuild -> android-build
println "rootDir=" + rootDir

include ':android-help:help'
project( ':android-help:help' ).projectDir = new File( rootDir, 'android-help/help' )

include ':android-setup:setup'
project( ':android-setup:setup' ).projectDir = new File( rootDir, 'android-setup/setup' )

include ':android-common:common'
project( ':android-common:common' ).projectDir = new File( rootDir, 'android-common/common')

include ':android-common:common-style'
project( ':android-common:common-style' ).projectDir = new File( rootDir, 'android-common/common-style')
```

all good until it gets to `android-common:common`, which depends on `android-common:common-style` with `compile project(...)`,

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':android-common:common'.
> Project with path ':common-style' could not be found in project ':android-common:common'.
```

what i'd really like is to do something like this for each project,

```
include ':android-common'
project( ':android-common' ).projectDir = new File( rootDir, 'android-common')
```

i.e., include *only* the top-level project build.gradle, but gradle doesn't like this and doesn't find any of the modules underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are redefining the location of the projects you should be able to write:

```
include ':common-style'
project(':common-style' ).projectDir = new File( rootDir, 'android-common/common-style')
```

This way you can make the project path (`:common-style`) match the paths of the projects when you only include `common` and `common-style`. This Gradle path doesn't have to match the on-disk path.

The goal is to have those projects have a constant paths whatever the setup is so that inter-project dependencies always look the same.